# How to take any image down to <300 bytes

Tags: image-processing

I would like to take an image (jpg/png) of varying sizes and convert it to a very small image file. I'll define very small as below 300 bytes.

Image quality is not of high importance (obviously). I'm thinking of the converted images being extremely pixelated into ~4 colors.

What is the best image format for this?

Is there an ImageMagick convert command to do this?

Comment: Extreme pixelization might work against you, as it almost ensures the pixel transitions will be close to random - this limits any additional compression. At 2 bits per pixel you're looking at only 1200 pixels, or 34x34. P.S. You'll need a custom format so you can lose all the header overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

Here is an ImageMagick command that does what you want:

```
convert <in>.<extension> -sample 1x1 -strip <out>.<extension>
```

The image quality suffers a bit, but as you said that's not very important to you.

And here is a probably more useful version:

```
convert <in>.<extension> -dither FloydSteinberg -resize 32x32 -colors 4 -strip <out>.gif
```

See below for more variations.  In the tests, GIF gave the smallest output.

## Tests

My results on a 1.7M test image `in.jpg`:

```
for type in jpg gif png; do convert -strip -sample 1x1 in.jpg out.$type; done
```

Then `ls` gives:

```
-rw------- 1 collins collins 1.7M Nov 13 16:04 in.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins  286 Nov 13 16:07 out.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins   43 Nov 13 16:07 out.gif
-rw------- 1 collins collins   82 Nov 13 16:07 out.png
```

So, looks like GIF and PNG are better choices, although JPG still gets you under the 300 bytes mark.

To get a better approximation to ~4 colors, you can do e.g.

```
for type in jpg gif png; do convert -strip -sample 2x2 in.jpg out.$type; done
```

although now the JPG is too large:

```
-rw------- 1 collins collins 1.7M Nov 13 16:04 in.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins  423 Nov 13 17:03 out.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins   50 Nov 13 17:03 out.gif
-rw------- 1 collins collins   93 Nov 13 17:03 out.png
```

And another way to get ~4 colors, which allows us to increase the output image size:

```
for type in jpg gif png; do
    for dither in None Riemersma FloydSteinberg; do
        convert in.jpg -dither $dither -resize 32x32 -colors 4 -strip out.$dither.$type;
    done
done
```

Now the GIFs and some of the PNGs make it in under 300 bytes:

```
-rw------- 1 collins collins 1.7M Nov 13 16:04 in.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins 1.9K Nov 13 17:30 out.None.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins 2.1K Nov 13 17:30 out.Riemersma.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins 2.1K Nov 13 17:30 out.FloydSteinberg.jpg
-rw------- 1 collins collins  225 Nov 13 17:30 out.None.gif
-rw------- 1 collins collins  229 Nov 13 17:30 out.Riemersma.gif
-rw------- 1 collins collins  234 Nov 13 17:30 out.FloydSteinberg.gif
-rw------- 1 collins collins  263 Nov 13 17:30 out.None.png
-rw------- 1 collins collins  332 Nov 13 17:30 out.Riemersma.png
-rw------- 1 collins collins  319 Nov 13 17:30 out.FloydSteinberg.png
```

E.g., here are the three output GIFs:

[image: dither=None]
[image: dither=Riemersma]
[image: dither=FloydSteinberg]

and the original:

[image: original]

Comment: I had to add --colors 256. Some of my images where still ~800 bytes. When I added that option, they went down to ~90 bytes. I'm not sure if this is coincidence, but this happened after uploading to S3, then downloading and converting.

Comment: Note that I used `-colors 4` to generate the actual example images.  I'll update the answer to make this more clear. Or are you saying that `-colors 256` made the result smaller than `-colors 4`?

Comment: I'll have to run some tests. IIRC, `-colors 256` went down to about the same size as `-colors 4`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using only a few exact colors for image then i would advice using GIF as it stores only indexes of colors in palette that is placed within the file, but not fully RGB. So you create a 4-colored GIF image in Photoshop and have only 2 bits (or like this) per pixel.
For more info about indexed colors and image formats that can keep them see [Indexed colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color)

Comment: Additionally, you could rescale (ie: downsample) the image. Between the compression and palette features of the GIF format, and downsampling to reduce the amount of data to compress, you're on your way.